# Appium SessionNotFound after test completes

Tags: java, android, selenium, testing, appium

I have the following Appium Testcase that completes all the steps successfully and quits the driver. But the result that is returned to the console is a session not found and im not sure why as all steps have completed successfully.

```
package amazon;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class StartApplication {

        private static AndroidDriver driver;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

            File classpathRoot = new File("C:\\workspace\\IJ Appium\\src\\resources\\Apps\\");
            File app = new File(classpathRoot, "IrishJobs_com.saongroup.irishjobs.apk");

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Craig Tab");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath() );
    //      capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "IrishJobs_com.saongroup.irishjobs");
    //      capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");

            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("Automation");
            driver.hideKeyboard(); 

            driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.Button")).click();

            Thread.sleep(150000);


            driver.quit();
    }

}
```

This is the error returned

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: 
Command duration or timeout: 24 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'IE-DUB-MOB-106', ip: '10.32.74.140', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{app=C:\workspace\IJ Appium\src\resources\Apps\IrishJobs_com.saongroup.irishjobs.apk, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=310096a22aefa200, platform=LINUX, desired={app=C:\workspace\IJ Appium\src\resources\Apps\IrishJobs_com.saongroup.irishjobs.apk, platformVersion=4.4.2, platformName=Android, deviceName=Craig Tab}, platformVersion=4.4.2, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, browserName=Android, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android}]
Session ID: 2be92a35-54c9-4eb6-b642-176e65e13070
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:526)
    at amazon.StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:42)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop the appium server, quit the simulator and relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Appium server closed the connection prematurely because of that long sleep. So when it finally comes to driver.quit(), the session is already ended.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been great if you could have shared the *appium server logs*.
But surely your `Thread.sleep()` time exceeds the `--command-timeout` which equals `60 sec`  - [details about server flags](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.0.0/?java#server-flags)

> The default command timeout for the server to use for all sessions.
>   Will still be overridden by newCommandTimeout cap

Though I wouldn't prefer adding this much of delays in the test. But still if the need be, you can add this to your server capabilities :

```
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "200");
```